# Cliente Api Rest en Java

Tags: java, rest

Estoy construyendo un cliente REST según el ejemplo https://www.flecharoja.com/blog/2017-11/integracion-factura-digital/ y tengo dos errores que no e podido corregir

Mi Codigo :

```
 public void ClienteApiRest()
    {
      javax.ws.rs.client.Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
      WebTarget target = client.target(IDP_URI + "/token");
      Form form = new Form();
                form.param("grant_type", "password")
               .param("username",usuario)
               .param("password", password)
               .param("client_id", client_id);
                Response response = target.request().post(Entity.form(form));
      JsonObject responseJson = response.readEntity(JsonObject.class);
      String acessToken = responseJson.getString("access_token");
      String refreshToken =responseJson.getString("refresh_token");
      jTextField1.setText(acessToken + " " + refreshToken);
    }
```

Los errores esta en estas lineas marco en negritas :

Response response = target.request().post(Entity.**form**(form));

JsonObject responseJson = response.**readEntity**(JsonObject.class);

¿ Que puedo hacer para corregirlos?

Comment: Para poder ayudarte es necesario que agregues el log del error.

Comment: Cannot find symbol, Symbol Method  form(Form),location interface @entity

Comment: Asegúrate de tener importadas las librerías correctas.

Comment: Las librerias estan importadas correctamente ...lo que me doy cuenta es que  Entity no posee un metodo form    ni response un metodo readEntity...sin embargo asi aparece en el ejemplo que menciono https://www.flecharoja.com/blog/2017-11/integracion-factura-digital/